# How to compare two generic types?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I make my class generic.The T - can be string or int.

I have this feature class:

```
public class Feature<T>// : IComparable
{
    public T CurrentFeatureCode { get; set; }

    public T StreetCode1 { get; set; }
    public T BuildingNumber1 { get; set; }
    public string BuildingLetter1 { get; set; }

    public T StreetCode2 { get; set; }
    public T BuildingNumber2 { get; set; }
    public string BuildingLetter2 { get; set; }

    public double CoordinateX { get; set; }
    public double CoordinateY { get; set; }

    public string Filter { get; set; }

    public string ToString(T streetCode)
    {
        return StreetCode2 == streetCode ? String.Format("{0}{1}", BuildingNumber2, BuildingLetter2) : String.Format("{0}{1}", BuildingNumber1, BuildingLetter1);
    }
}
```

As you can see I have ToString method inside Feature class that compares two values:

```
StreetCode2 == streetCode ? String.Format("{0}{1}", BuildingNumber2, BuildingLetter2) : String.Format("{0}{1}", BuildingNumber1, BuildingLetter1);
```

I  get error on this row:

```
Error   11  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T' .
```

My question is how can I compare two values of T type?

Comment: `int streetCode` is not `T StreetCode`

Comment: @CSharpie thanks it's mistake

Comment: You can't compare them because T might be of different types. Naturally, `==` can't be used if every type might be on any side of it.

Comment: Where is your code for how you use this class? How are you closing the generic? That is the important part and you have not shown it. What is `T`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Well, there can be a subclass relationship, but both `Streetcode2` and `streetCode` are compatible with type `T`. There's only one `T` type here - it's not like `ToString` is generic introducing a new type parameter.

Comment: Do you want to Compare Features ?

Comment: @JonSkeet well it took a few reads but I get what you mean and what is my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

For your type `T`, implement the [`IEquatable<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx). Override the `Equals()` method with logic that suits your case. Note that you must override `GetHashCode()` as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy with the default comparer, then you can do this:

```
public class Feature<T>// : IComparable
{
    public T StreetCode2 { get; set; }
    public string ToString(T streetCode)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(StreetCode2, streetCode))
        {
            return "Equal";
        }

        return "Not Equal";
    }
}
```

And here is a test:

```
var feature1 = new Feature<string>();
feature1.StreetCode2 = "two";
string equals = feature1.ToString("two");
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the recommended approach would be to use the IEquatable interface with generics and the Equals() method, but I am not sure if that suits your tastes.